# Can we Install Ubuntu Cinnamon Remix Desktop on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I have installed ubuntu server in my machine and I live cinnamon Remix desktop. This is different from default cinnamon desktop flavor.

can anyone tell me how can we install this on ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu Cinnamon remix desktop is as simple as installing a metapackage. It doesn't matter whether the base system was originally server or desktop.

```bash
sudo apt install ubuntucinnamon-desktop
```

I found this by running `apt search cinnamon desktop` and finding the right result. Usually each Ubuntu flavor's desktop environment's package name ends in `-desktop`.